# Why is my Core Data migration crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, migration

You may also get some use out of [a post I made that relates to the same task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46174543/core-data-migration-could-not-cast-value-of-type-nsmanagedobject-mytype-to-m):

I'm trying to migrate and old data store to a new object model, and so lightweight data migrations are not going to work.  I'm using a Mapping Model and then some custom `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` subclasses that are mainly used to define helper methods that I can then call from the Mapping Model.

I've been learning by doing, and each step of the migration process will fail, then I fix it, then it goes a bit further, then I get stuck.

So I seem to have passed the validation step and the models will save, but now I'm getting a hard crash when calling this on the NSMigrationManager:

```
                 [manager migrateStoreFromURL:sourceStoreURL
                                         type:type
                                      options:nil
                             withMappingModel:mappingModel
                             toDestinationURL:destinationStoreURL
                              destinationType:type
                           destinationOptions:nil
                                        error:error];
```

And it's one of those unhelpful crashes because it's EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I can't find out where or what exactly is causing it.  I do know that the stack trace in the debugger looks like:

```
    (lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2c8)
frame #0: 0x000000010ac97ac5 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 5
frame #1: 0x000000010b1911e3 CoreData`_PFManagedObject_coerceValueForKeyWithDescription + 1187
frame #2: 0x000000010b16d9d7 CoreData`_sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 231
frame #3: 0x000000010b1e4e18 CoreData`-[NSEntityMigrationPolicy createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:] + 744
frame #4: 0x000000010b22aa67 CoreData`-[NSMigrationManager(InternalMethods) _doFirstPassForMapping:error:] + 407
frame #5: 0x000000010b22c1a3 CoreData`-[NSMigrationManager(InternalMethods) _migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:error:] + 2003
frame #6: 0x000000010b228d59 CoreData`-[NSMigrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:error:] + 777
```

So based on frame#1, I'm guessing it's trying to migrate a NSNumber to a scalar.  Could this be possible?   I'm wondering if anyone has migrated an older store to a newer store where scalars are allowed.

Comment: Questions should stand on their own. If this question needs other details then post those details in this question. Don't post a link to another question with those details.

Comment: I didn't.  I added it in case someone was doing something similar and these are 2 mutually exclusive parts of a larger task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it was crashing is because something was defined in the Mapping Model that referenced most likely custom code, and that code failed.

If you have an Entity Mapping that isn't straightforward, I would recommend removing all property mappings from that entity mapping, then override:

```
func createDestinationInstances(forSource sInstance: NSManagedObject, in mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager) throws
```

Where you specify exactly what the properties should be.  It might also have to do with one of these custom methods passing back an instance of a SUBCLASS of `NSManagedObject`, which you should NOT do during a migration.

You can see in the stack trace of the original question that it failed trying to convert one value to another "coerceValueForKey..."

For example:

```
override func createDestinationInstances(forSource sInstance: NSManagedObject, in mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager) throws {

    let dInstance = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: mapping.destinationEntityName!, into: manager.destinationContext)

    let text = sInstance.value(forKey: "text") as! String?

    dInstance.setValue(sInstance.value(forKey: "lastModified"), forKey: #keyPath(Song.createdAt))
    dInstance.setValue(sInstance.value(forKey: "lastModified"), forKey: #keyPath(Song.updatedAt))
    dInstance.setValue("txt",                                   forKey: #keyPath(Song.fileExtension))
    dInstance.setValue(sInstance.value(forKey: "filename"), forKey: #keyPath(Song.filename))
    dInstance.setValue(sInstance.value(forKey: "firstLetterUppercase"), forKey: #keyPath(Song.firstLetterUppercase))
    dInstance.setValue(sInstance.value(forKey: "name"), forKey: #keyPath(Song.title))
    dInstance.setValue(sInstance.value(forKey: "oldFilename"), forKey: #keyPath(Song.oldFilename))
    dInstance.setValue(self.songDataLengthOfText(text), forKey: #keyPath(Song.songDataLength))
    dInstance.setValue(text, forKey: #keyPath(Song.text))
    dInstance.setValue(SongDataType.plainText.rawValue, forKey: #keyPath(Song.typeRaw))
    dInstance.setValue(nil, forKey: #keyPath(Song.userInfoData))

    // my new data model added a to-one association to a Song that wasn't present previously.  So we have to create it,
    // but not yet associate it.  We just provide a means to associate it, via the filename/songFilename
    let songData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: SongData.entity().name!, into: manager.destinationContext)
    songData.setValue(sInstance.value(forKey: "filename"), forKey: #keyPath(SongData.songFilename))
    let structure = SongDataStructure()  // don't worry about this.  It's used for serialization.
    structure.set(text: text)
    songData.setValue(structure.serialize(), forKey: #keyPath(SongData.nsdata))

    // my new data model added a to-one association to a Song that wasn't present previously.  So we have to create it,
    // but not yet associate it.  We just provide a means to associate it, via the filename/songFilename
    let viewPreferences = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: SongViewPreferences.entity().name!, into: manager.destinationContext)
    viewPreferences.setValue(sInstance.value(forKey: "filename"), forKey: #keyPath(SongViewPreferences.songFilename))

    // important to associate these!
    manager.associate(sourceInstance: sInstance, withDestinationInstance: dInstance, for: mapping)
    return
}
```

Comment: "I would recommend removing all property mappings from that entity mapping" -- Thanks for this! I thought custom mapping would override property mappings. I so happens that it tries all property mapping listed even if the entity is set to custom mapping.